# Controls look different at runtime and design time

Tags: c#, winforms, flat

I have a regular button (or any other control), which at design time looks 3D like this:

[image: 3D]

And at runtime looks flat like this:

[image: Flat]

Of course I want it to look 3D, but I can't see any reason, option or property to make it 3D. I thought that maybe it's a .NET issue, but even targeting .NET 4.5.3 didn't help.

P.S: Obviously I have windows 7, so this can't be the issue

Comment: enable VisualStyles in your app

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you. It worked! Can you post the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` method is called by default in the static void `Main()` method, inside the `program.cs` file. Maybe you're maintaining an older app, or someone removed that line at some point. Check to see if it's missing.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // Enable visual styles for your application.
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Technically, you can call that method from anywhere in your application, but then controls that have already been drawn may retain the older "flat" look. Best to leave it in the `program.cs` file, and execute it before you start up the message loop for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into `Form_load()` :

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

is what you need to add to program.cs