# Why does my form look so different after publish vs release?

Tags: vb.net, format, styles, release, publish

I've went to publish my first vb.net windows form and was surprised the format I meticulously combed over became all skewed after publishing.

[image: See attached]

Why did the controls change to older style '3d' and the overall ratio of the form stretched in the horizontal? My calendar date pickers also changed format.

Is there a way to make the published form look exactly like the release version, down to the pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control visual styles before you create your UI thread, but VB.Net will enable visual styles for you in Sub Main, which is inaccessible to you! You can get around this by creating your own Sub Main, but you also need to choose this new method as the entry point to your application.

```vb
' in a new class file, I called Program.vb
Public Module Program
    <STAThread>
    Public Sub Main()
        Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NonClientAreaEnabled
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub
End Module
```

In the project properties, click Startup object, choose Program

[image]

My Form1 has two TextBoxes. Here's the code

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.TextBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
    End Sub
End Class
```

and here is the result

[image]

Note with `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` instead, I'm getting all single borders.

[image]

Hope some setting of visual styles does the trick

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I like the look of your second result. Where do I place Application.EnableVisualStyles()? I put it in the newly created public Sub Main() but then my published program fails to start up.

Comment: Did you change the startup object?

Comment: Yes, it runs with everything you said, I just got stuck on the last part “enablevisualstyles”

Comment: I’m bummed out that I simply don’t get  what I see in the debug/release mode and that it will take much more finessing with guess and check to get right. I guess the actual game play footage is always worse than the game trailer!

Comment: In Application settings do you have "Enable Application Framework" enabled?

Comment: I turned that off, and now cannot turn it back on whatever I try. I get the message “Startup object must be a form when ‘Enable application framework’ is checked.

Comment: Oh what .NET version are you using?

Comment: Application framework is what creates the hidden Sub Main, so your startup object would be the initial form you load. But without it you can still make a winforms app but you just need to handle all the stuff that it does manually. I think we're getting far away from your issue, sorry it's not resolved yet. It might be something different...

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28650482/832052) is similar

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I am better off to have that checked - I’m running .NET framework version 4.8.04084 in visual studio community 2022 version 17.2.1

Comment: It looks like this is a current bug as per this thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-doesnt-permit-to-change-s/10049115

Comment: Oh that is terrible :/ I wouldn't have suggested this if I had known. Btw, many problems with .NET Framework (as opposed to .NET core) in VS2022. I have encountered many others to the point where I use VS2019 for .NET Framework projects

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, this is an amazing community. How to I acknowledge your answer?

Comment: You can upvote this answer if it helped but since it didn't solve the problem you don't need to click the checkbox to accept it. I appreciate it. FYI an accepted answer gives the author 15 reputation, any upvote gives 10.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing appearance issues, I can share that in my case, this seems to be related to my project starting first in visual studio 2019 and then I changed over VS 2022. I am happy to report that as soon as I copied my code over to a clean project in 2022, everything works great! The published copy looks completely identical to the release/debug version and I didn’t need to play with any settings in the Main Sub!
Thank you djv for working with me!