# 'Sub Main' was not found in, BC30420 VS 2022 17.2.5

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I can't change the "Startup object" it only shows "Sub Main" in the list without anything else, what happened is that I initially changed "Form1" name to "FormLogin",I changed the form name twice:

1. First I Rename from "Design>Name" from "form1" to "FormLogin"
2. Then I Rename the file name with Click-Right>Rename from "form1.vb"
   to "FormLogin.vb"

And made additions inside the form and the program worked fine, and then I decided to add another form After I added it and added modifications to it, I wanted to test them, so I went to Properties in order to modify it to the other form, but suddenly I saw the "Startup object" changed instantly from "Form1" to "Sub Main" and I can't modify it

Comment: What .Net version are you targeting?

Comment: i use .Net  4.7.2

Comment: Add to the question: - the version of Visual Studio in use - a description of how you renamed the Form. -- If you have VS 2022, to change the startup Form, go to Solution Explorer, click the `Select All file` button, expand `My Project`, double-click `application.myapp`, edit `<MainForm>Form1</MainForm>`  to set `Form1` (or whatever that is) to the Form you want to set as starting Form. -- I assume your Project configuration file (`.vbproj`) uses the old format.

Comment: Is [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-doesnt-permit-to-change-s/10049115) the same?

Comment: @djv Yes, this is still a problem in VS 2022. What's in the Project file, `application.myapp` and what is reflected in `My.MyApplication` is not consistent. Trying to set a different startup object may disable `Application Framework` without having the chance to reset it to the previous state using the old UI (VB.Net doesn't have the new Project properties UI template). --  One could use the new Project Format, then manually set `<StartupObject>[NameSpace].[FormName]</StartupObject>` and `<TargetFramework>[Version]</TargetFramework>`

Comment: I didn't know it was a bug, I searched the internet for a solution all of them were old and didn't work, thanks Jimi The "MainForm" part wasn't there so I tried adding it and it didn't work either, looks like it's for another version or what? '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyApplicationData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MySubMain>false</MySubMain>
  <MainForm>Form1</MainForm>
  <SingleInstance>false</SingleInstance>' ....etc

Comment: [It came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384675/why-does-my-form-look-so-different-after-publish-vs-release/72385194#comment127895718_72385194) a little while back in another question I was trying to help with, and I inadvertently recommended the OP try to change it, then it broke his project :/

Comment: @DEVTE There's an example of creating a `Sub Main` in [How to find the main() entry point in a VB.Net winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307397/1115360) if that helps.

Comment: You have to set `<MySubMain>true</MySubMain>` (`true`), then `<MainForm>Form1</MainForm>`. With default settings, in `application.myapp` you should also have: `<SingleInstance>false</SingleInstance><ShutdownMode>0</ShutdownMode><EnableVisualStyles>true</EnableVisualStyles><AuthenticationMode>0</AuthenticationMode><SaveMySettingsOnExit>true</SaveMySettingsOnExit>` -- This supposes that you haven't tampered with the Project's configuration files somewhere else and that you have renamed your Form correctly (which is not clear at all from your minified description. Try with a numbered list)

Comment: thx @AndrewMorton and jimi its worked now, But I can't change anymore from the Startup object it just runs the form I'm writing, the strange thing is that I made a new project and copied the file of both 'Application.myapp' and
'Application.Designer.vb' and I modified 'WindowsApp1' to the name of the project, but there were a lot of errors in the 'Application.Designer.vb' file, for example it tells me:
"'MainForm' is not a member of 'MyApplication'"

Comment: @DEVTE How did you get it to work? I just ran into the same issue just by trying to change the startup to another Form!, then all forms disappeared from the lists, and not event able to go back to the Form I had as a startup.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of searching, it seems that it is a defect:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-doesnt-permit-to-change-s/10049115
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Startup-Form-Dropdown-List-Not-Populated/10049171

As a workaround which worked for me. Create a `Shared Sub Main` and add the below code, with the `Form` you would like to run.

`Program.vb`

```
Public Class Program

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Application.Run(New [Form])

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Update**

Updating VS2022 to Version 17.3.6 fixed the issue, now all `Forms` appear in the drop-down list `Startup Project`.